# JS-Search function fails

Tags: javascript

I want to search in a table. i copied a workin JS from a tutorial site.
it worked perfectly

to see the original working configuration -> http://jsfiddle.net/9T9CZ/4/

just type something in the text box, eg Flower, if you want to search for flower.

After my modification, which was adding a new `<tr>` with a `<div>` inside, the search stopped working.

mod.Fiddle Version: http://jsfiddle.net/9T9CZ/5/

Firebug breaks if you type any letter in the search-box with: `targetTable.rows.item(...).cells.item(...) is null`

I belive this problem is the emty div in the new `<tr>`

Does anyone has an idea to correct this or to work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, adding a `colspan` breaks your code. Instead of detecting only the amount of the cells in the first row, you need to check each row.

The snippet below does the trick. I've also simplified your code a bit.

```
function doSearch() {
    var searchText = document.getElementById('searchTerm').value.toLowerCase(),
        table = document.getElementById('dataTable'),       
        text = (document.body.textContent) ? 'textContent' : 'innerText', // Feature detection
        rows = table.rows, // Caching rows
        rLen = rows.length, 
        r, rowText, cells, cols, c;

    for (r = 1; r < rLen; r++) { // Ignoring the first row
        if (rows[r].className.indexOf('some_classname') < 0) {continue;} // className check
        rowText = '';
        cells = rows[r].cells; // Caching the cells
        cols = cells.length;
        for (c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
            rowText += cells[c][text];
        }
        rowText = rowText.toLowerCase();
        if (rowText.indexOf(searchText) < 0) {
            table.rows[r].style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            table.rows[r].style.display = 'table-row';
        }
    }
}
```

- Feature detection for `innerText`/`textContent` instead of browser detection.
- Ignoring the `thead` starting the `r`-loop from `1` (the only permitted direct content of [`thead`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/thead) is `tr`)
- Caching `.rows` and `.cells` collections makes the code faster

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4rze3/).

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfectly. Is there any way to affect just rows that have a specific class?

Comment: @HKK It's possible, please see my edited answer (there are some other fixes too). Also, to avoid your question getting down/close votes in the future, please add the JS from your second fiddle, and the HTML for _one_ `tr` with an empty `div`. If the external code source will not be available, your question will lack the most important information needed to understand it, and hence it will be useless for future visitors.